# Whats the difference between open and native handle in c#

Tags: c#, memory, process, handle

I am looking for the difference between

```
IntPtr handle_1 = process.Handle;
```

> Gets the native handle of the associated process.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(
     uint processAccess,
     bool bInheritHandle,
     uint processId
);
IntPtr handle_2 = OpenProcess(0x0010,false,process.Id);
```

> If the function succeeds, the return value is an open handle to the specified process.

Both got different values. But i can still read the memory with those. I would like to understand the difference between those two, to prevent making mistakes.
I am using them in the context:

```
 ReadProcessMemory(handle_x, addr, data, data.Length, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are process handles, and as such can be used in the same manner.

A `Process` object contains a process handle through its `Handle` property. When you call `Dispose` on that object, you close that handle.

When you call `OpenProcess` on the process' ID, you get a *different* handle (so it has a different value) that refers to the same process. You must separately close that handle when you're done with it (using the Win32 function `CloseHandle`): disposing the `Process` object won't magically close the handle you got from `OpenProcess`.

So why would you call `OpenProcess` when you already have a perfectly functional handle in `Process`? Well, access rights, really. The handle obtained by `Process` has `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` (i.e. full access rights). If you want an handle with fewer rights, you can use `OpenProcess` for that.

But really, for most purposes, there isn't really a need to mess around with native APIs when you need a process handle.

Comment: Thank you Etienne de Martel. Your answer is sufficient enough for me. :)